# Modifying a LGPL licensed image to create iPhone app icons

Tags: iphone, image, icons, lgpl

I would like to use icons under the LGPL license in an iPhone application. I want to modify these icons (size, color or more advanced editing) in order to fit my app requirements.

I understand that the modified versions inherit the license. But embedding the app in an iPhone makes it harder to share the images and license files.

My questions are :

- do you credit the authors ? If yes where ? "About" screen ?
- Where do you put the copy of the GNU LGPL text ?
- How do you make your modified version available to the community (under the LGPL license) ? Is it acceptable to publish it on the wikimedia commons ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007940/how-to-use-lgpl-licensed-images-in-a-proprietary-application

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You may be able to get help on [Programmers Stack Exchange, but **read their faq carefully** before proceeding.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there even an accepted interpretation for what the LGPL means when applied to binary assets like an icon? It's pretty clearly geared for source code, which is the reason a lot of the Creative Commons licenses came about.

Without knowing the answer(s) to the above, I'd say you could create an "About" screen that contained the appropriate copyright acknowledgements, and host the modified versions of the icons on a public web page that is linked from the about screen.